# Is this how to find the sum of two sub-spaces over $R^3?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I just started teaching myself linear algebra from Sheldon Axler's book$.$ It says that the sum of the sub-spaces of a vector space $V$ is just the sum of the elements of the sub-spaces$.$ As an example to see if I understand the concept$,$ I created two vector spaces on $R^3,$ and they are $:$

$U = \{(a, b, c), (d, e, f)\}$

$W = \{(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)\}$

and if I'm reading my textbook correctly$,$ the sum is $:$

$U + W = \{(a, b, c) + (1, 2, 3), (d, e, f) + (4, 5, 6)\}$

$ = \{(a + 1, b + 2, c + 3), (d + 4, e + 5, f + 6)\}$

Is this correct$?$

Comment: U and V, as you describe them are pairs of vectors, so aren't subspaces. U+V is the sums of an element of U and an element of V, *in all possible ways*.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Also, I forgot that subspaces have the additive identity, and are closed under multiplication and scalar multiplication. I'll have to edit this question later.

Comment: Under multiplication? $\mathbf R^3$ is not naturally an algebra.

Answer (score 0):

$U$ and $W$ aren't vector spaces, but since you understand that, I think they will help to illustrate the concept. When you add two subspaces together, you don't just take the sums of every set of "corresponding" vectors; you add *every combination* of vectors, where in each combination you take one vector from each of the spaces. Thus, if $U$ and $W$ were subspaces of $V$, their sum would look like this:

$U + W = \{(a,b,c)+(1,2,3), (a,b,c)+(4,5,6), (d,e,f)+(1,2,3), (d,e,f)+(4,5,6)\}$